# How do you pass a variable to FullCalendar ResourceViews URL

Tags: php, variables, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullCalendar plugin for jQuery and I'm having an issue with passing a variable.

Basically, what I want to is create a search and pass the search input to the url of the resource option.

I have a search code and it looks like this

```
<form action="employees.php" method="POST"> 
    <input type="text"   name="name" size="25" maxlength="230" 
           style="margin-left:5px;" value="" />
    <br /> 
    <p style="padding-top:10px; margin-left:5px;">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
   </p> 
</form>
```

my employees.php with the Calendar script looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'resourceWeek',
        refetchResources: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        numberOfWeeks: 1,
        weekends: false,
        firstDay: 1,    
        editable: false,
        selectable: false,
        refetchResources: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        resources: 'resource_employee.php',
 // more code
        ?>
```

my resource_employee.php page looks like this

```
<?php
// some connection code
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[name]);

//$name = 'Goo'; 

//$result = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS name, employeeID FROM ecc_employee WHERE first_name != '' ");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS name, employeeID FROM ecc_employee WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%$name%' ");

$resources = array();

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){            
    $name = ($row['name']);
    $id =  $row['employeeID'];

    $resources[] = array(
    'name' =>  "$name",
    'id' => "$id"
    );

}
echo json_encode($resources);

?>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't return anything because the $_POST[name] doesn't get pulled into this page because it's in the script.

If I uncomment //$name = 'Goo'; then it will render, so I know it's not the SQL, it's getting that $_POST.

How can I get the $_POST[name] into the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to get the $_GET['employeename'] by doing the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'resourceWeek',
        refetchResources: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        numberOfWeeks: 1,
        weekends: false,
        firstDay: 1,    
        editable: false,
        selectable: false,
        refetchResources: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        resources: 'resource_employee.php?employeename=<?php echo $_GET['employeename']; ?>',
        events: 'events.php',
```

Easy enough, don't know why it hadn't been answered in any of the other questions about this.  Hope this saves time for some poor guy out there.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `$_POST['name']` with single quotes

Comment: I used `$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);` and it still didn't work.